Chrome Extension for Chrome Bookmarks - to see the folder path for each Bookmark in a search result
Need a way (Chrome Extension?) to do this:

when you search Chrome (browser) Bookmarks for a particular word or phrase,
the search result shows you relevant bookmarks,
and next to each bookmark, you can see its folder path (by "folder path" we mean the path in the bookmarks tree).

As an example, let's say you search for the phrase: quick recipe . You would get an output that looked something like this.

If you know how to do this, please share. Thank you.
